# Communication between ViewModels in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel

I'm trying to implement communication between my view models in a `knockoutjs` driven application. I scaffolded it using `yeoman` tool, and as you can see it uses `AMD`:

```
define(['knockout', 'signals', 'text!./nav-bar.html'], function(ko, Signal, template) {

    function NavBarViewModel(params) {
        this.route = params.route;
    }

    return { viewModel: NavBarViewModel, template: template };

});
```

I have to define an object that I would later use to dispatch events, right? Something like that:

```
var EventDispatcher = {
    itemClicked: new Signal()
};
```

And then, whenever something happens in the `NavBarViewModel` I'd like to do:

`EventDispatcher.itemClicked.dispatch();`

The problem is - where should I put this EventDispatcher thing? It's obvious that it should be some kind of a global object, so that every VM could get a hold on it, but it would be ugly. Dependency injection came to mind, since everything else in this architecture I choose is done this way, but how to achieve that? I come from `WPF, MVVM` world, and so far I've used MVVMLight framework which had this great `Messenger` component. Is there anything like that in the JS world (and if it's `js-signals` lib I'm already using, then how should I use it to achieve my goal?)

I could also use the `subscribable` object built into the knockout fw, but the question still stands - where to put it (or how to share the instance between VMs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd quite simply inject it by including it in your `define`.

First, create a new file, *EventDispatcher.js* with your `EventDispatcher` code inside (and other relevant Knockout bits, like returning the view model and whatnot).

Then in your current file add it in:

```
define([ ... , ... , "EventDispatcher"], function( ... , ... , EventDispatcher )
```

Now you can simply call its methods within this file by using:

```js
EventDispatcher.itemClicked.dispatch()
```

(Where `EventDispatcher` is what we've named it in our `define` parameters).

Do bear in mind though that your `EventDispatcher.js` file will also need the `signals` file passed to it through its own `define` wrapper.

Comment: A second before you published this answer I discovered this: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox . Which is a bit nicer, because I don't need to include more dependencies on any of my VMs - it just adds some functionalities to Knockout :). However you answer the exact question I was asking, so I'm accepting your answer.